# Primefaces jquery easing (not a function) error

Tags: jquery, primefaces

I've got recently the following error in the firebug console:

```
TypeError: jQuery.easing[this.easing] is not a function
```

This is the error in **PickList** component, when clicking on move button or double click on element (dragging actually works).

I've found sugestions on various foras that this is problem with more then one version or jquery on the page, ev. more than one copy of primefaces.jar in classpath, however both are not the case here.

This is my header:

```
<head>
        <meta content="IE=edge,chrome=1" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
        <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
        <link href="/qmwebui/javax.faces.resource/theme.css.xhtml?ln=primefaces-qmui" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="/qmwebui/javax.faces.resource/primefaces.css.xhtml?ln=primefaces" type="text/css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="/qmwebui/javax.faces.resource/jquery/jquery.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces" type="text/javascript">
        </script><script src="/qmwebui/javax.faces.resource/primefaces.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces" type="text/javascript">
        </script><script src="/qmwebui/javax.faces.resource/hotkey/hotkey.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces" type="text/javascript">
</head>
```

**PrimeFaces** version **3.4**, server **Websphere 7.0**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, and spent a lot of time to solve it. The problem is that I added the effect="none" to picklist, but that value is not allowed here (which is really stupid, because none is allowed anywhere where you can put effect). Without effect attribute everything works fine.

Comment: Well, it seams that the naming conventions inside PrimeFaces aren't fully consistent, and there's no validation on some attributes either...